# Ontology Matching Evaluation

Tags: owl, matching, ontology

fellow students and I have developed an Ontology Matching Algo. in a student project.
We thus chiefly evaluate our algo. on the oaei dataset
(http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/) but we would like to test it on other as well.

Does anyone know others datasets or challenges as oaei?

Comment: Top-level ontologies; Wikidata vs. DBpedia?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thats not exactly what we are looking for, 
we want to compare ourselves with others